# How to override search results sort order in Plone

Tags: search, overriding, plone

Plone search functionality is implemented in the [plone.app.search](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.search) package; the **sort_on** variable included in the request is used to control the sort order of the results on the [search template](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.search/blob/master/plone/app/search/search.pt).

By default, when this variable has no value, Plone uses **relevance** as sort order.

What's the easiest way of changing this to **date (newest first)**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to customize the search view to set new sorting options, and to alter the default sort when no sort has been set.

If you still need to be able to sort by relevance, use a non-empty value that you then change in the `filter_query` method:

```
from plone.app.search.browser import _, Search, SortOption

class MyCustomSearch(Search):
    def filter_query(self, query):
        query = super(MyCustomSearch, self).filter_query(query)

        if 'sort_on' not in query:
            # explicitly set a sort; if no `sort_on` is present, the catalog sorts by relevance
            query['sort_on'] = 'EffectiveDate'
            query['sort_order'] = 'reverse'
        elif query['sort_on'] == 'relevance':
            del query['sort_on']

        return query

    def sort_options(self):
        """ Sorting options for search results view. """
        return (
            SortOption(self.request, _(u'date (newest first'),
                'EffectiveDate', reverse=True
            ),
            SortOption(self.request, _(u'relevance'), 'relevance'),
            SortOption(self.request, _(u'alphabetically'), 'sortable_title'),
        )
```

Then register this view to your site; if you use a theme layer that'd be easiest:

```xml
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    i18n_domain="plone">

    <browser:page
        name="search"
        layer=".interfaces.IYourCustomThemeLayer"
        class=".yourmodule.MyCustomSearch"
        permission="zope2.View"
        for="*"
        template="search.pt"
        />

    <browser:page
        name="updated_search"
        layer=".interfaces.IYourCustomThemeLayer"
        class=".yourmodule.MyCustomSearch"
        permission="zope2.View"
        for="Products.CMFCore.interfaces.IFolderish"
        template="updated_search.pt"
    />

</configure>
```

You'll need to copy over the `search.pt` and `updated_search.pt` templates from the `plone.app.search` package.

Comment: thanks! I fixed your solution to reflect the final working code but I can't see the modifications.

Comment: @hvelarde: your suggested edit was a little radical for the reviewers; I updated my version from yours.

Comment: who are these reviewers anyway? people know nothing about Plone and they feel they can review an editing? thanks!

Comment: @hvelarde: Editing should only really be used to fix spelling, grammar and such. All users over 2k can review.

Comment: Shouldn't the `import` line read `from plone.app.search.browser import _, Search, SortOption`?
(no `SearchOption` there, and you use `SortOption` in the further code)

Comment: @Tobias: well spotted! Yup, there is no `SearchOption` name in that module.